# Long lag before login after suspend-resume 17.10

Tags: login, 17.10, suspend, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

### Problem

When resuming from system suspend there is a long wait/lag (maybe `30 secs`) between login and the desktop appears. This is not present on login from a cold boot.

### Background

The workstation is fairly fast, 2.4 GHz x4 i5 / 8 GB RAM / 500 GB SSD, and I initially installed Ubuntu many years ago. As such, the current OS **17.10 - Gnome** is an upgrade from **17.04 - Unity**. On **17.04** this issue was not present. Immediately after finishing the upgrade to **17.10** I began having slowness getting to login screen after resume, and it's been like that ever since. Therefore, I think it's an issue with Gnome somehow.

### Additional Details

- after waking, the disk drive (SSD) I/O indicator lights up solid until login appears; so basically the OS is thrashing the drive after resume.
- the monitors light up, but are blank, until login screen
- I do not have hibernation enabled
- Swap size is `16 GB` and currently using `8.4 GB` after `13 days` uptime. The uptime doesn't impact the problem, but I'm not sure swap should be using 8.4 GB and that might be an issue.

### Request

I don't know where to begin diagnosing or troubleshooting. Please respond with any ideas, regardless of how basic, even if you don't have a solution.

Thank you!

### Edit to Add

---

Here is the log filtered by "warning" and above. Note, the moment of suspend was `13:39` and resumed at `15:10:59` (ish).

`Mar 20 15:11:03 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2809]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Mar 20 15:11:01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1766]: Window manager warning: Failed to set power save mode for output LVDS-1: Permission denied
Mar 20 15:11:01 wpa_supplicant[1467]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3s0 flags: No such device
Mar 20 15:11:00 wpa_supplicant[1467]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Mar 20 15:11:00 wpa_supplicant[1467]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Mar 20 15:11:00 gnome-shell[2809]: Could not release device 13,79: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.DeviceNotTaken: Device not taken
Mar 20 15:11:00 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
Mar 20 15:11:00 systemd-sleep[25077]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Mar 20 15:11:00 acpid[959]: input device has been disconnected, fd 19
Mar 20 15:11:00 gsd-rfkill[2892]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
Mar 20 15:11:00 gsd-rfkill[2892]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
Mar 20 15:10:59 console-kit-daemon[1674]: WARNING: Error waiting for native console 1 activation: Resource temporarily unavailable
Mar 20 15:11:00 729C63FBC5D69A70B75C53893A4F75E090944EDE.google-chrome-service.desktop[3015]: [3015:3062:0320/151059.689818:ERROR:cloud_print_proxy_backend.cc(571)] Notifications for connector 3AD85577-2573-887A-BC8C-031ECFF3EAB4 disabled.
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: usb 1-1.1:1.1: rebind failed: -517
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: usb 1-1.1:1.0: rebind failed: -517
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel: usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel:  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel:  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 15:11:00 kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 34: no longer affine to CPU3
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU3
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 12: no longer affine to CPU3
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 9: no longer affine to CPU3
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 1: no longer affine to CPU3
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 35: no longer affine to CPU2
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 23: no longer affine to CPU2
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ 37: no longer affine to CPU1
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: IRQ fixup: irq 1 move in progress, old vector 117
Mar 20 15:10:59 kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Mar 20 13:39:06 systemd-sleep[24799]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 254.
Mar 20 13:39:00 729C63FBC5D69A70B75C53893A4F75E090944EDE.google-chrome-service.desktop[3015]: [3015:3062:0320/133900.838428:ERROR:cloud_print_proxy_backend.cc(571)] Notifications for connector 3AD85577-2573-887A-BC8C-031ECFF3EAB4 disabled.`

Comment: look at the file `/var/log/syslog` and find the time where your machine resumed. Then copy those lines into your question so we can see what is running slow.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've updated the OP.